# Invoke amplify login form by clicking login button

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I understand how to invoke login dialog automatically when going to a protected page, this can be done by wrapping the page in `<Authenticator>` component, like this:

```
function Profile(props: any) {
    return <Authenticator>
      {({ user, signOut }: any) => {
        return <>
          <div>Profile: { user.username }</div>
          <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
          </>
      }}
    </Authenticator>
}
```

But how can I show login dialog after clicking "login" button? And how can I dismiss it? This is very basic login functionality, that's how it is implemented on airbnb for example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you considered looking [here](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/configuration)?

Answer (score 1):

I completed the question with this code below, copying most of the code from [this example](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/customization):

```
import { Authenticator, Button, Heading, Image, Text, useAuthenticator, useTheme, View } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { useState } from "react";

const components = {
    Header() {
      const { tokens } = useTheme();
  
      return (
        <View textAlign="center" padding={tokens.space.large}>
          <Image
            alt="Amplify logo"
            src="https://docs.amplify.aws/assets/logo-dark.svg"
          />
        </View>
      );
    },
  
    Footer() {
      const { tokens } = useTheme();
  
      return (
        <View textAlign="center" padding={tokens.space.large}>
          <Text color={tokens.colors.neutral[80]}>
            &copy; All Rights Reserved
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    },
  
    SignIn: {
      Header() {
        const { tokens } = useTheme();
  
        return (
          <Heading
            padding={`${tokens.space.xl} 0 0 ${tokens.space.xl}`}
            level={3}
          >
            Sign in to your account
          </Heading>
        );
      },
      Footer() {
        const { toResetPassword } = useAuthenticator();
  
        return (
          <View textAlign="center">
            <Button
              fontWeight="normal"
              onClick={toResetPassword}
              size="small"
              variation="link"
            >
              Reset Password
            </Button>
          </View>
        );
      },
    },
  
    SignUp: {
      Header() {
        const { tokens } = useTheme();
  
        return (
          <Heading
            padding={`${tokens.space.xl} 0 0 ${tokens.space.xl}`}
            level={3}
          >
            Create a new account
          </Heading>
        );
      },
      Footer() {
        const { toSignIn } = useAuthenticator();
  
        return (
          <View textAlign="center">
            <Button
              fontWeight="normal"
              onClick={toSignIn}
              size="small"
              variation="link"
            >
              Back to Sign In
            </Button>
          </View>
        );
      },
    },
    ConfirmSignUp: {
      Header() {
        const { tokens } = useTheme();
        return (
          <Heading
            padding={`${tokens.space.xl} 0 0 ${tokens.space.xl}`}
            level={3}
          >
            Enter Information:
          </Heading>
        );
      },
      Footer() {
        return <Text>Footer Information</Text>;
      },
    },
    SetupTOTP: {
      Header() {
        const { tokens } = useTheme();
        return (
          <Heading
            padding={`${tokens.space.xl} 0 0 ${tokens.space.xl}`}
            level={3}
          >
            Enter Information:
          </Heading>
        );
      },
      Footer() {
        return <Text>Footer Information</Text>;
      },
    },
    ConfirmSignIn: {
      Header() {
        const { tokens } = useTheme();
        return (
          <Heading
            padding={`${tokens.space.xl} 0 0 ${tokens.space.xl}`}
            level={3}
          >
            Enter Information:
          </Heading>
        );
      },
      Footer() {
        return <Text>Footer Information</Text>;
      },
    },
    ResetPassword: {
      Header() {
        const { tokens } = useTheme();
        return (
          <Heading
            padding={`${tokens.space.xl} 0 0 ${tokens.space.xl}`}
            level={3}
          >
            Enter Information:
          </Heading>
        );
      },
      Footer() {
        return <Text>Footer Information</Text>;
      },
    },
    ConfirmResetPassword: {
      Header() {
        const { tokens } = useTheme();
        return (
          <Heading
            padding={`${tokens.space.xl} 0 0 ${tokens.space.xl}`}
            level={3}
          >
            Enter Information:
          </Heading>
        );
      },
      Footer() {
        return <Text>Footer Information</Text>;
      },
    },
  };
  
  export default function App() {
    const [showAuthentication, setShowAuthentication] = useState(false)
    if(showAuthentication) {
        return (
            <>
            <button onClick={() => setShowAuthentication(!showAuthentication)}>Close dialog</button>
                <Authenticator components={components}>
                    {({ signOut }) => <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>}
                </Authenticator>
            </>
          );
    }
    else {
        return (
            <button onClick={() => setShowAuthentication(!showAuthentication)}>Login</button>
        )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to reuse UI too.

Comment: So you want to see if they have an account, and conditionally show the correct functionality?

Comment: yes, they should see some information anyway, plus some private info if they choose to log in